# Suppress warning from natbib/multibib with silence

Tags: natbib, warnings, multibib

I fail to suppress the warning

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Entry' multiply defined.
```

using the `silence` package when using natbib and multibib. This is my MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: bibtex: {files: [Other]}
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Entry, Title="Title"}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{Other}{Other}

\usepackage{silence}
% does not compile:
%\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation `#1
% works, but unwanted:
%\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation `}
% does not work:
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation `\#1' multiply defined}

\begin{document}
    \let\myjobname\jobname

    \cite{Entry}
    \citeOther{Entry}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliographystyleOther{plainnat}

    \bibliography{\myjobname}
    \bibliographyOther{\myjobname}
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to run `bibtex` on `Other.aux` manually if you do not use `arara`.

Am I perhaps doing something wrong with the escaping of `#1`?

**Edit:** I should have been a little more specific. I would like to use the starred version of the the `WarningFilter` so I can suppress this message for different bibtex entries. I just need to know how to teach `silence` to work with `#1`.

Comment: You can say `\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation}`; this will suppress warnings beginning with "Citation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what I need cannot be done. Here is some evidence:

First, it seems that `#1` is never seen by `silence`, as this MWE shows:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
% works, but too unflexible:
% \WarningFilter{mypackage}{Suppress me}

% does not compile:
% \WarningFilter*{mypackage}{#1}

% this does nothing:
\WarningFilter*{mypackage}{\#1}

% in fact, this at least works for the first one:
\WarningFilter*{mypackage}{\TheWarning}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\IssueWarning}[1]{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{#1}}

    \newcommand{\TheWarning}{Suppress me!}
    \IssueWarning{\TheWarning}

    \IssueWarning{Suppress me, this may even be more difficult!}
\end{document}
```

In fact, I my original MWE, this works:

```
% works:
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation `Entry' multiply defined}
```

Note that this is the starred version of `WarningFilter`!

From the `silence` doc, I assume that only one unique starred version of `WarningFilter` can match a (complete) given warning, so this must be it.

Why is that?

`natbib` issues the warning like this:

```
\renewcommand\bibcite[2]{\@ifundefined{b@#1\@extra@binfo}\relax
     {\NAT@citemultiple
      \PackageWarningNoLine{natbib}{Citation `#1' multiply defined}}%
```

So looking for the culprit call to `\bibcite`, I found:

```
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#5}{{#1}{#2}{{#3}}{{#4}}}}}\fi
```

Removing this `\bibcite`, the error message is indeed removed, and indeed, in both aux files I usually find this:

```
\bibcite{Entry}{{Ent}{}{{}}{{}}}
```

So the `\bibcite` call issuing the warning does not contain anything which would make a usable difference between `\WarningFilter` and `\WarningFilter*`, it seems.

What can in any way be learnt is that, for the purpose of `silence`, `#1` needs to be tracked down recursively to find what it ultimately was. If it was plain text (such as in my second `\IssueWarning` example), `\WarningFilter*` does not offer any advantage.

**Edit**: A very simple patch of `natbib` would involve something along the lines

```
\newcommand{\HashOne}{#1}
```

before and replacing `#1` by `\HashOne` in the warning line.

Comment: There is a similar issue with the `graphics` package. I guess that the `#1` is resolved before it gets to `silence`. Interesting patch though, but I guess it'll be unlikely to get it implemented unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

You can say

```
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation}
```

and this will suppress all warnings beginning with "Citation"; in particular, it will suppress the

```
Citation `#1' multiply defined
```

from `natbib`. This, however, might not be what you want since `natbib` has other warning messages beginning with the string "Citation"; in this case, you could use

```
\WarningFilter{natbib}{Citation `Entry' multiply defined}
```

instead; notice the un-starred version, so you are targeting the warning message as it appears in the `.log` file.

Your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Entry, Title="Title"}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{Other}{Other}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation}

\begin{document}
    \let\myjobname\jobname

    \cite{Entry}
    \citeOther{Entry}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliographystyleOther{plainnat}

    \bibliography{\myjobname}
    \bibliographyOther{\myjobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try. I edited the question to make more clear that I look for an answer which

1. works for many bibtex entries at a time, 
2. without removing all warnings starting with "Citation"

Note, in particular, this part of my MWE:

    % works, but unwanted:
    %\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation `}